# Is it okay to say "My two next lesson"?

Tags: grammar

If I intend to talk about my lesson which is two lessons later, can I say "my two next lesson" ?
You can think that I used three different cars last month and try to represent the car which is the first one of these three cars. So, can I say "my two previous car was not satisfactory" ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the grammar. But it is extremely awkward and would very likely not be understood as you intend.

Comment: @puppetsock Well, what can I say instead?

Comment: The car I had two before my current car was not satisfactory.  The lesson scheduled two after the current lesson will be on that topic.

Comment: Your sentences are not at all natural. "The lesson after next ..." and "The first of the cars I used last month..."

Comment: @puppetsock thank you very much, first of all. I have one more question related to that, can we shorten these sentences like "The car two before my current car" and "The lesson two after the current lesson" ?

Comment: In Britain we might say 'my next lesson but one'.

Comment: my third lesson (If there are only three lessons) ; my last lesson (if it is the last one); my lesson after the next two (two lessons later)

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion doesn't work in English. We tend not to use this kind of *relative*  determiner but an *absolute* determiner instead.  For example, although there is a word "tomorrow" there is no word for the next day after tomorrow.  We are forced to use "The day after tomorrow" or other clumsy expressions, so normally we would say "On Saturday" (given that today is Thursday)

So you would normally find some other way to specify the lesson.  While you can say "My lesson after next",  it might be more natural to say "My 12:15 lesson" (for a lesson that starts at 12:15).

Similarly, you might say "The red Ford" to identify the car which you used before two other cars this month, assuming that the colour and the maker is enough to identify the car.

> In the next lesson we will finish off our work on differentiation, and then on Tuesday we will have a short test, followed by an introduction to integral calculus on the 25th.

> Do you remember the car that I had at the start of the month? The red Ford Fiesta? I loved that car.